# im having trouble with git push ive t

Tags: github

```
stizz@Stizzys-Mac code % cd homework 
stizz@Stizzys-Mac homework % cd work-day-scheduler 
stizz@Stizzys-Mac work-day-scheduler % git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    Work-Day-Schedule
    modified:   script.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
stizz@Stizzys-Mac work-day-scheduler % git add . 
stizz@Stizzys-Mac work-day-scheduler % git commit -m "script.js update"
[master eba02ca] script.js update
 2 files changed, 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 160000 Work-Day-Schedule
stizz@Stizzys-Mac work-day-scheduler % git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

stizz@Stizzys-Mac work-day-scheduler %
```

Comment: just do what the error message suggests. which part of the error message is not clear?

Comment: Please revise the title to actually explain the problem. Did you read the output from git?

Answer (score 0):

```
% git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Git told you what to do to fix the problem, but let's go over what that means.

`git push` needs to know which remote to push it to and what branch on that remote to push it to. The remote is usually origin and in this case you want to push to its master branch. Spelling it out explicitly is `git push origin master`.

But a branch can have an "upstream branch" meaning it already knows where to push to. Then you can `git push` and Git knows where to push to. `git push --set-upstream origin master` pushes your branch to the master branch on origin and remembers that for the future. From then onward you can `git push` and it will go to origin's master branch.

You can also do this without pushing: `git branch -u origin master`.